# Press behaviour Ionic / Angular / Cordova App in mobiles

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, touch

This is something that is bugging me a lot. I see a lot of hybrid apps made in HTML5/JS that present this problem. To date, I havent found a reliable solution.

The problem is that, in mobile, with the regular and more used angular event: (click), as so:

`<button (click)="dosomething()"></button>`

There are 2 major problems:

1. When you press on it, and you do a long press, it will never, ever call the click action. If you havent defined or coded a long press, this a very very very very very bad UI behaviour. The "tap" is, therefore, badly implemented. If you go to your android calculator, you'll see that when you press a number, and wait 5 seconds, when you release, it will trigger. Which is how it should work.
2. If you press it and move slightly, the action will not trigger. This is also something that is quite bad for UX purposes.

Does anyone know a solution to this or an alternative?

Comment: how about using mouseup event than click event?

Comment: I tried, but the movement problem (2) still occurs. If I press it and move slightly, on mobile phones, it does not trigger.

Comment: Are you using ionic framework? I have build ionic angular cordova app and have never seen this issue.

Comment: Yes, Ionic. I thought this was an angular related problem. Note that in browsers this works perfectly. Only in mobile the behaviour is wrong.

Comment: @ArunSelin so yes, I am using Ionic. Why? Is there something that you experienced with ionic?